# How to restrict user to type in textfield after typing some characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am using textfield in my application and I want to restrict user typing only 15 characters in the textfield. After that he/she **should not be able to type** in the textfield.

How can I set this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of a trick to this, you need to calculate what the new string will be before you can test whether to allow or deny the change

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ([newString length] > 15) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//its big code but working fine for me

//put Your Text Field Name instead of YourTextFieldName in this code

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string

     {

      if (textField==YourTextFieldName)
      {

        NSString *text = nil;
        int MAX_LENGTH = 12;

        text = YourTextFieldName.text;
        if ([text length] <= 7)
         {
            NSString *separator = @"-";
            int seperatorInterval = 3;
            NSString *originalString = [textField.text         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:separator withString:@""];

            if (![originalString isEqualToString:@""] && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
            {

                NSString *lastChar = [YourTextFieldName.text substringFromIndex:[YourTextFileName.text length] - 1];
                int modulus = [originalString length] % seperatorInterval;

                if (![lastChar isEqualToString:separator] && modulus == 0)
                {
                    YourTextFieldName.text = [YourTextFieldName.text stringByAppendingString:separator];
                }
            }
        }
        if ([text length] > 7)
        {
            NSString *separator = @"-";
            int seperatorInterval = 6;
            NSString *originalString = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:separator withString:@""];

            if (![originalString isEqualToString:@""] && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
            {

                NSString *lastChar = [YourTextFieldName.text substringFromIndex:[YourTextFieldName.text length] - 1];
                int modulus = [originalString length] % seperatorInterval;

                if (![lastChar isEqualToString:separator] && modulus == 0)
                {

                    YourTextFieldName.text = [YourTextFieldName.text stringByAppendingString:separator];
                }
            }
        }

           NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
         return (newLength > MAX_LENGTH) ? NO : YES;
     }
    return YES;



     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if typing and count chars

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range      replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
    if (range.length > 15) {
        // delete
    }
    else
    {
        // add
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (([textField.text length] - range.length) == 15) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length >= 15)
    {
        return NO; //return NO to not change text
    }

return YES;

}
```

Comment: it wont allow deletion of characters once 15 characters have reached.